# Why Hibernate Hi-Lo Algorithm Strategy multiply the sequence by 50?

Tags: hibernate

I am using *Hibernate 5.3.7*. After setting `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` defaults from true to false, unique constraint error is resolved.

But facing a different behavior of id creation :

Id generated by Hibernate =  ( 50 * (start_with) value of the Oracle sequence) + 1

Is this the default behavior of Hilo Algorithm?

Thanks in Advance.

Suggested Approach - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10983

Hi- Lo : https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hilo-algorithm/

I can read hat hi and lo value will be calculated on 
[(hi -1) * incrementSize) + 1, (hi * incrementSize)) 
By Default the incrementSize is 50.

What is the reason behind multiplying the start_with value by 50?

For Example:

I have a table with a sequence start value of 5000

Then my Hibernate application will start from (5000 * 50) = 250000

Pooled Strategy - Ended in unique-constraint exception

And also: How the Oracle sequence is communicated on used ids ?

As per this website, Gaps in id's are normal:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:369390500346406705

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE, sequenceName = SEQUENCE)
private Long titId;`

Got a warning like this below:

Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead. See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.

Then changed my code to SequenceStyleGenerator:

`@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="cmrSeq", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQUENCE")}
    )
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_name")
private Long titId;`

This solved my two issues:

1) The deprecated warning is fixed 2) Now the id is generated as per the oracle sequence.